# Add form choices as options in a select tag html

Tags: html, django

I'm in my final project and I'm a little bit lost on what I'm doing now. 
I'm developping a website and I need to insert some choices into a html select tag, I mean, that choices must be options of this select tag. I'm trying it, but the dropdown doesn't appear as it should, and, when I try to submit my form, it gives me an error. I wish you could help me, I'm becoming crazy. Here I leave my code, feel free to ask anything you want

forms.py

```
class FormCancion(forms.ModelForm):

    NOTAS_CHOICES=(('35','Acoustic Bass Drum'),('36','Bass Drum 1'),('37','Side Stick'),('38','Acoustic Snare'),('39','Hand Clap'),
    ('40','Electric Snare'),('41','Low Floor Tom'),('42','Closed Hi Hat'),('43','High Floor Tom'),('44','Pedal Hi-Hat'),
    ('45','Low Tom'),('46','Open Hi-Hat'),('47','Low-Mid Tom'),('48','Hi-Mid Tom'),('49','Crash Cymbal 1'),('50','High Tom'),
    ('51','Ride Cymbal 1'),('52','Chinese Cymbal'),('53','Ride Bell'),('54','Tambourine'),('55','Splash Cymbal'),
    ('56','Cowbell'),('57','Crash Cymbal 2'),('58','Vibraslap'),('59','Ride Cymbal 2'),('60','Hi Bongo'),('61','Low Bongo'),
    ('62','Mute Hi Conga'),('63','Open Hi Conga'),('64','Low Conga'),('65','High Timbale'),('66','Low Timbale'),('67','High Agogo'),
    ('68','Low Agogo'),('69','Cabasa'),('70','Maracas'),('71','Short Whistle'),('72','Long Whistle'),('73','Short Guiro'),
    ('74','Long Guiro'),('75','Claves'),('76','Hi Wood Block'),('77','Low Wood Block'),('78','Mute Cuica'),('79','Open Cuica'),
    ('80','Mute Triangle'),('81','Open Triangle'))

   nota_pad_gris = forms.ChoiceField(choices=NOTAS_CHOICES, widget=forms.Select())
```

views.py:

```
def crearCancion(request):

    cancion=Cancion()
    if request.method=="POST":
        formulario=FormCancion(request.POST,request.FILES,instance=cancion)
        if formulario.is_valid():
            formulario.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/ListadoCanciones/')
    else:
        formulario=FormCancion()
        context={'formulario':formulario}
        return render(request,"nuevaCancion.html",context)
```

.html:

```
<br><br><br>
    <div class="container">
        <form id='formulario' method='post' {% if formulario.is_multipart %} enctype="multipart/form-data" {% endif %} action=''>
            {% csrf_token %}
            <center>

                <label for="nota_pad_gris">Nota del pad Gris:</label>
                    <select id="nota_pad_gris" onchange="validar();">
                       {% for value in formulario.nota_pad_gris %}
                        <option value="hola">{{ value }}</option>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </select>

            <br><br>
            <p><input type='submit' class="btn btn-success btn-lg" value='Añadir'/>
             <a href="/ListadoCanciones/" type="input" class="btn btn-danger btn-lg">Cancelar</a></p>
            </center>
    </form>
    <br>
</div>
```

Edit:

Look at Nota del pad gris. This is what the list shows. It shows the choices, but also shows a blank space between the choices. 
[[image: 1]]

This is the error that the web gives me when I try to submit the form
[image]

Comment: First of all try with {{ form.as_p }} to see if it works or not. I think the problemo lies with this {<option value="hola">{{ value }}</option>}
value="hola" will ensure that all the entries in the select will have the same value as hola

Comment: Could you please post the error, probably that is causing because you didn't give any name to your select field.

Comment: I just updated the post with some images, the error that I receive and what the dropdown shows. @PankajSharma

Comment: May the problem lies on what you say, do you know anyway to solve this? @ChetanGanji

Comment: Yes i do. Re the choices in the select options, render the form using form.as_p and see if it works fine. If yes, open chrome developer tools and copy the raw html of that part and paste it besides the above code in your html files. Compare and contrast and bingo, you solved your problemo.

Comment: Re the form error, after submitting the form you are redirecting to a new url. HttpResponseRedirect('/ListadoCanciones/'). This url does not return a http response. Look for the response of the get method of above url. I would just return redirect(reverse("url-name"))